# How do I determine all acceptable values for object properties in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've gotten to a point in working with Powershell that I don't need to have a book or reference manual by my side for most tasks. I still have to search here or MSDN from time to time but it is far less frequent nowadays.

A lot of information on Powershell is readily available but you just need to know where to look. And this is where I am stuck.

What I want to do is list all acceptable property values for a given object without having to pull up the MSDN documentation (which is dryer than insulated ceiling tiles). Don't misunderstand me here; I'm not asking to list current or default properties for an object, I just want to list a property of an object and see what options I have available.

Here is an example of what I am **not** talking about:

```
New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell" | gm
```

or:

```
(New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "Powershell").FileName
```

Those second one queries the current or default value for that particular named property. The first one will list a table with `Name`, `MemberType`, and `Definition`. `Definition` will give the type, handle, parameters, and\or `{get; set;}` (depending on whether the `MemberType` is a `method`, `property`, `event`, etc).

Say I would like to set that particular property--how do I know what values are valid and which are not?

What I **am** talking about would be something along these lines:

```
(New-Object Windows.Forms.Form).FormBorderStyle | gm
```

or:

```
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.FormBorderStyle | gm
```

For the `FormBorderStyle`, valid assignable values are: `None`, `FixedSingle`, `Fixed3D`, `FixedDialog`, `Sizable`, `FixedToolWindow`, or `SizableToolWindow`. The only way I found these was through an the text rendered during an exception. How would I go about finding those values without having to rely on exceptions?

Ideally, I don't want to have to keep searching MSDN, TechNet, or StackOverflow. Is there a cmdlet or query that I can use within Powershell (outside of get-help or man) to give me that information? Get-Help\man aren't very useful when it comes to a smaller and more defined scope.

Without saying "Google it", "RTFM", or "get good", what advice do you all have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, `FormBorderStyle` is an enum, so this will work:

```
[enum]::getvalues((New-Object Windows.Forms.Form).FormBorderStyle.gettype())
```

Quick note: my sentence does not imply that this will not work in other cases. The same syntax is valid for any enum.

Credit to @TheMadTechnician, another possible syntax:

```
[Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle].GetEnumNames()
```

It's also possible to combine both, if you can't bother to look up the enum's name:

```
(New-Object Windows.Forms.Form).FormBorderStyle.gettype().GetEnumNames()
```

Comment: I typed `New-Object Windows.Forms.Form | gm` but it didn't list FormBorderStyle as `[enum]`. I did see that when I typed `((New-Object Windows.Forms.Form).FormBorderStyle).GetType()`. For other types, is there a way to list values like you did with your given answer? I didn't need `FormBorderStyle`, I just used it as an example. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Or even more simply: `[Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle].GetEnumNames()` where you could try that that with anything that you suspect will have a list of valid values.

Comment: @Rincewind I don't think there is. In your example, `Form` is an object, so each member of that object can have values that depend on its type... Some of those will be enums, but others will be integers, for example. Apart from documentation, I don't think there's a means to know what values are accepted. I may be wrong, though.